# Why global var type variable is not accessible outside $.each when using in $.post method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, var

I was going through a piece of code when I found that this variable is throwing an error.

```js
function call(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    var ddlId = 'ddlCat' + data[index].docId;
    var html = '<tr id="supp_doc_row_' + data[index].docId + '" class="cls-delete-dynamic_edit">';
    var html2 = '';
    var countDocOfsameCategory = parseInt(data[index].countt) - 1;
  })

  $.post('/someController/SomeAction/', {
    requestType: 'GETDOC'
  }, function(data1) {
    $("#" + ddlId).empty();
    $("#" + ddlId).append($('<option value= "Select"> Select Type</option>'));
  })
}
```

Now the problem is that i was treating this **ddlId** variable as global. So I had used this inside post method.  But I got this in my console.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ddlId is not defined
>
> ```
> at Object.success (<anonymous>:1110:38)
> at u (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
> at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
> at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
> ```

When I debugged it in console then I found that in $.each call it had value but in $.post it has gone.

Can any one tell me how this global variable lost its state?

Comment: `ddlId` is not global. You defined it within the `each()` block. This is easier to see now that I edited your question so the logic is indented properly. You also have some missing `)` which will be causing syntax errors.

Comment: This doesn't even look like valid code, there are a variety of mismatched parentheses and curly braces.  Are you *sure* this is the actual code you're using?

Comment: @David Its not the whole code just a piece of it. I will edit this.

Comment: @RajanMishra: Well, at least start with syntactically valid code.  The browser console will tell you of your syntax errors much more efficiently than we will.  Also, if you're only using the last value in your `data` then why use `.each()` at all?  Just get the last value and use it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` makes the variable `global` for the specific scope. A `var` defined inside a function can be accessed inside the function anywhere but won't be accessible outside because it is not its scope. Define the `var` in the global scope outside the function and all your functions will have access to it.

Comment: Thanks it was a huge confusion i was having this whole time. please vote up.

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking, mark the answer as correct so that it can help others too.